# Connect Draw.io to Google Drive

Tags: google-chrome, google-drive

I am trying connect Draw.io to Google Drive. I think the problem may be the browser cookies because I can connect Draw.io to Drive when I use the Incognito mode in Google Chrome.

I have deleted the Chrome data, stopped the Chrome synchronization, deleted the application and downloaded it again, but...

Also, I have [checked if my browser (Chrome) allows 3rd-party cookies](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/50990/connecting-to-google-drive-using-draw-io).

What do you think?

Comment: Have you got the disconnect plugin installed?

Comment: Of course, but I obtained the same error.

Comment: No, have you got it installed, i.e. whitelist the site.

Comment: Yeah, I think the cookies are the problem source.

Comment: Since this is likely a browser issue and not a question about using Draw.IO, I'm going to send this over to Super User where browsers/extensions are on-topic.